# Objective-C get a class property from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, properties

I've heard a number of similar questions for other languages, but I'm looking for a specific scenario.

My app has a Core Data model called "Record", which has a number of columns/properties like "date, column1 and column2". To keep the programming clean so I can adapt my app to multiple scenarios, input fields are mapped to a Core Data property inside a plist (so for example, I have a string variable called "dataToGet" with a value of 'column1'.

How can I retrieve the property "column1" from the Record class by using the dataToGet variable?

Comment: Probably using KVC. Didn't understand your question exactly. Do you want to retrieve a property who's name can be entered by user?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The [Key Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i) mechanism allows you to interact with a class's properties using string representations of the property names. So, for example, if your `Record` class has a property called `column1`, you can access that property as follows:

```
NSString* dataToGet = @"column1";
id value = [myRecord valueForKey:dataToGet];
```

You can adapt that principle to your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, not only does that solve my immediate problem, but will no doubt help with future situations as well.