# How to dynamically change a property that is being accessed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I'm programming a game that has 40 levels and I'm storing all my level data in a .plist. This works great but now that I'm trying to implement multiple levels, I'm looking for a way to call a property on a singleton based on level without manually coding something like a switch/case. I would like to do something like the following:

This is the code I use to pull my data but as you can see, I've hard coded the "dictionaryLevel1Data" property.

```
int capacity = [[sharedDataManager.dictionaryLevel1Data objectForKey:@"typeWarrior"] intValue];
```

I would like to set a variable and have the property of the singleton called based on that like this which I know doesn't work. Notice how I'm replacing "dictionaryLevel1Data"

```
NSString level = @"1";

int capacity = [[sharedDataManager.[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dictionaryLevel%@Data", level] objectForKey:@"typeWarrior"] intValue];
```

Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. I can always go and manually setup a switch/case for each level but with 40 levels and 50+ different object types per level it would be rough, it seems like there must be a better way. I hate hard coding values and like to simplify my code with easy updates to variables that run through generic classes and methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want do it this way, then you can use Key-Value-Coding, to get a property value from a string. The accepted answer in this post shows how to use it (very easy): [Objective-C get a class property from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179427/objective-c-get-a-class-property-from-string)

For your task it would look something like this:

```
int capacity = [[[sharedDataManager valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dictionaryLevel%@Data", level]] objectForKey:@"typeWarrior"] intValue];
```

Comment: Thank you Johannes! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thanks for also linking the other post as it lead me to an answer to another questions I had. Cheers! :0)

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it could also solve a second problem!

Answer (score 1):

why don't you do like this;

use 2 level data map;

```
//sharedDataManager.levelData is a NSDictionary that contains lots of NSDictionarys
NSDictionary *levelData = [sharedDataManager.levelData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dictionaryLevel%@Data", level]];

int capacity = [levelData objectForKey:@"typeWarrior"] intValue];
```

Comment: Thanks...this was my fallback option. I just really like the suggestion from Johannes. Take it easy and thanks again for such a quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
NSString level = @"dictionaryLevel1Data"
SEL methodSelector = NSSelectorFromString(level);
if ([sharedDataManager conformsToSelector:@selector(methodSelector)]) {
    NSDictionary *levelData = [sharedDataManager performSelector:methodSelector];
    // Do whatever you need here
}
```

I assume all dictionaryLevelData are synthesized and have getters as their name.

(Note that I did not compile it but it should work)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This could have worked too...just like the valueForKey which I had never seen before in the suggestion from Johannes. Thanks again.