# How to convert an NSString to id or UIView objective-c iphone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

How can I convert my `NSString *myString = @"myUIView";` to the UIView: myUIView so that I can use the UIView in my code?

I have a string that I'm changing to the name of the view.

I would like to change views using the name of the view that is in my NSString so my Nsstring might be set to "self.view" but I'm changing it every time I switch a view using the UIView transitionFromView:**self.view** toView:View2 duration:0.4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished) {}

but how can I replace the bolded part with my string that is the name of the UIView not in a string form (because it won't work)

Comment: I don't understand you question? Do you want to display the NSString?

Comment: Your Problem is not clear can u explain it plss

Comment: How do you expect an NSString to be converted to an UIView?

Comment: You can make a `UILabel` with that string (which derives from `UIView`)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C get a class property from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179427/objective-c-get-a-class-property-from-string)

Comment: upvoted only because I want to see what he really wants! :- )

Comment: Its amazing that 3 very different answers have popped up. Also amazing that someone downvoted mine lol. Apparently we aren't allowed to help the guy.

Comment: yeah, wasn't me, I thought that was weird also...

Comment: Three answers that each solve a different problem is a pretty good sign of a terrible question.

Comment: Good point Josh, good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets you a UIViewController loaded from a xib.

```
    Class vcClass = NSClassFromString (@"myUIView");
    UIViewController *detailViewController = [[vcClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"myUIView" bundle:nil];
```

If you just wanted a UIView object, just do:

```
    UIView* myView = [[vcClass alloc] init];
```

But really, as the three answers so far show it isn't clear at all what you what. Can you be clearer? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `myUIView` defined as a property, e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *myUIView;
```

then you can access it from a string with the `-valueForKey:` method, as in

```
[self valueForKey:@"myUIView"]
```

Comment: This is a good answer.
Another possible solution is, in case you generate the views programmatically, to preload all UIView objects in a dictionary:
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myView1,@"myView1",myView2,@"myView2",nil];
and then access the view in this way:
UIView *aView = viewDictionary[@"myView1"];

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display the `NSString` you do so by using a `UILabel` which is a subclass of `UIView`. You don't "convert" the `NSString` to a `UIView`. The `NSString` is a data structure that needs to be rendered using a `UIView` subclass.

The code below will put your string on the screen.

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
[myLabel setText:myString];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```