# How can i get the property of NSObject using NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop

I'm developing for the iPhone. Is there any way to get a property using an  NSString holding the property name? something like:

```
@interface MyLovelyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) double test;

-(double) returnDoubleProperty:(NSString *) propertyName;
```

and then to call it

```
MyLovelyClass *mlc=[[MyLovelyClass alloc] init];
double value=[mlc returnDoubleProperty:@"test"];
```

I understand that if i have a limited number of properties, i can manually write if else statements that would return values for each input string. However, is there any way to achieve this programmaticaly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179427/objective-c-get-a-class-property-from-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use KVC (key value coding) which does exactly what you describe, but you don't need to implement any methods for it to work. It does work with objects though so your `double` would be wrapped inside an `NSNumber`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *test;

NSNumber *value = [mlc valueForKey:@"test"];
```

Comment: would it work with any descendant of NSObject?

Comment: Wain, seems to be the best way to achieve what i wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Since properties are methods, you can call them through `performSelector:`. To make a selector from string use `NSSelectorFromString`. The `double` will be wrapped in an `id` object of type `NSNumber`, so you need to pull it back by calling `doubleValue`:

```
SEL toCall = NSSelectorFromString(@"test");
double value=[[mlc performSelector:toCall] doubleValue];
```