# extract UIButton object from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsstring

I want to hide already created UIButton object of same name as contents of string myBtnName

```
 NSString *str=@"first";
 NSString *myBtnName=[str stringByAppendingString:@"Btn"];
```

myBtnName is (NSString *) and has value of @"firstBtn"... How do i make it (UIButton*) firstBtn ?... Please Help

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to create a UIButton variable named as the contents of the string? Or set the button title?

Comment: I want to hide already created UIButton object of same name as contents of string

Comment: Look at this accepted answer for using Key Value Encoding

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179427/objective-c-get-a-class-property-from-string

Comment: If you would save not `NSStrings` but integers you could give the `UIButton` on instantiation a tag number and then get the `UIButton` via `UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tmpTag];`

Comment: thanks David Somen... It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is unclear to me, but if you want to get a button that you defined as a property by it's name you can use this:

```
NSString* myBtn = [str stringByAppendingString:@"Btn"];
UIButton* button = [self valueForKey:myBtn];
```

Answer (score 2):

don't under stand your question properly but i get your problem little bit. that you want to set title of button by appending your variable try this:
  this will append your text i.e @"Btn" with your variable: hope this helps.. :)

```
    UIButton *btn = [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Btn",yourVariableString]   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: It will create a new UIButton... i want to access existing UIButton of the name same as contents of string

Comment: ok, you want to set your button name same as your variable text? m i right?

Comment: I wanted to hide already created button who's name was in contents of NSString....

UIButton* button = [self valueForKey:myBtn]; button.hidden=YES; worked fine for me

Answer (score 2):

```
UIButton *button = [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Btn",yourVariableString]   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```